# The child row is not accessible in child component using Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular7-router

I just started to learn Angular 7 and I'm a little confused about routing.
I created a route configuration in app-routing module and child row in message-routing module.

I expect these routes:

```
/
/message
/message/inbox
/message/new
/about
```

But routes inside messageComponent are not accessible:

> Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'message/new'

These are my configurations:

**app-routing.module.ts:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'message',
    component: MessageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**message-routing.module.ts:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'message',
    component: MessageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: InboxComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'new',
        component: NewComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MessageComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MessageRoutingModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And this is my folder structure:

[image: Folder structure of my Angular app]

Comment: Can you also provide your app.module.ts please

Comment: Thanks @Wandrille. I added app.module.ts

Comment: Where are you importing `message-routing.module.ts` ?

Comment: Can you add your message-routing.module.ts before your AppRoutingModule

Comment: @Wandrille Wow. I didn't import the message-routing.module !!! I imported it into app.module.ts but the problem still exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by Adding Inbox and New components to the message-routing.module.ts. I'm not sure if here is the best place to add them but this solved the problem.

**message-routing.module.ts:**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'message',
    component: MessageComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: InboxComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'new',
        component: NewComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [InboxComponent, NewComponent],
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example :

*child-routing.module.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'child,
    component: ChildComponent
    canActivate: [YourGuard],
    children: [{
      path: '',
      component: ChildAComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'some-route',
      component: ChildBComponent
    }]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  providers: [YourGuard],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ChildRoutingModule { }
```

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'other-route,
    component: OtherComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And in *app.module.ts*:

```
...
import:[
   ChildRoutingModule,
   AppRoutingModule
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't find my problem. I did the same in my example but the child path is not accessible.